# Python :: requests auth

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape a website using BeautifulSoup. The website requires a login.

https://www.bahn.de/p/view/meinebahn/login.shtml

Researching the web I understand that one proper way to get authorization is using `requests`.

My code looks as follows:

```
url = 'https://www.bahn.de/p/view/meinebahn/login.shtml'
header = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5)AppleWebKit 537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome","Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp    ,*/*;q=0.8"}

user = "username"
pwrd = "password"

response = requests.post(url,headers = header, auth=(user, pwrd))
page = requests.get('https://fahrkarten.bahn.de/privatkunde/meinebahn/meine_bahn_portal.go?lang=de&country=DEU#stay')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
```

This does not work unfortunately as `soup` is an html text stating amongst others "You are logged out of our system". Although the result of `response` is `<Response [200]>`

I am a bit struggling with `auth`for two reasons:

1. is my understanding of the auth method even correct, i.e. first post the login details and then get access to a website which is "behind" the login) or does this work differently?
2. how do I find out if a website requires a more special auth method? Are there keywords to look for in the html code?

Any help would be appreciated as I really want to understand it and I am apparently to "newbie" to get the right conclusions from the manuals (e.g. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to figure out how authentication works for a website is to **capture the traffic while logging in**, and **find out** what happens behind the scene: **which URL is used, what data is submitted etc**.

You could use `fiddler` or `charles`, or the most convenient Chrome Dev Tools (F12 to initiate), it's like this:

[image: login request]

And in your case the whole request is:

```
POST /privatkunde/start/start.post HTTP/1.1
Host: fahrkarten.bahn.de
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 74
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: https://www.bahn.de
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: https://www.bahn.de/p/view/meinebahn/login.shtml
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

scope=bahnde&lang=de&country=DEU&username=demo&password=demo&login-submit=
```

Most importantly, because **cookie is used for authentication/verification, a session is needed for the whole process** and later to be used to access other web pages which are accessible to logged in user only.

```
import requests

session = requests.Session() # create a session that handles cookies by default

headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5)AppleWebKit 537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome"
          ... # simulate headers that is used in the actual POST request
} 

data = {'scope': 'bahnde', 'lang': 'de', 'country': 'DEU', 
        'username': 'xxxx', 'password': 'xxxx', 'login-submit': ''
       }

# now login
response = session.post(url='https://fahrkarten.bahn.de/privatkunde/start/start.post', data=data, headers=headers)

# once logged in, session can be used to access other web pages
# sometimes you also want to make sure it actually logged in by checking content from response.text
content = response.text 
# try to look for your username or other flags with content.find etc. 
r2 = session.get(url='xxx') # access other pages
```

Comment: THANKS!! It works. I am quite a newby and get stuck sometimes, because I am lacking the background knowledge. So thanks for your explanations. This really helps!! Maybe a somewhat stupid questions. How do I know that cookies are being used here?

Comment: Well, when you browse a website with modern browsers such as Chrome/Firefox, cookies are being taken care of automatically by the browser. `requests.Session()` provide a session which takes care of cookies by default (similar as how a browser does it), and at any given time you could always use `session.cookies` to check out the content.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It is likely because you request the wrong page, look at the form in the login page :

```
<form method="post" name="staticLogin" id="kv-static-logi" action="https://fahrkarten.bahn.de/privatkunde/start/start.post">
<input name="scope" value="bahnde" type="hidden">
<input name="lang" value="de" type="hidden">
<input name="country" value="DEU" type="hidden">
<p>
<input id="kv-static-login-username_ab" name="username" class="from" maxlength="60" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Benutzername" type="text">
</p>

<p>
<input id="kv-static-login-password_ab" name="password" class="from" maxlength="60" placeholder="Passwort" type="password">
</p>

<p><button type="submit" name="login-submit" class="btn slim no-margin" style="float: left">Login</button>
<a id="vergessen" href="https://fahrkarten.bahn.de/privatkunde/start/start.post?scope=pwvergessen&amp;lang=de">Login vergessen?</a>
</p></form>
```

You should request the page `https://fahrkarten.bahn.de/privatkunde/start/start.post` with the `username` and `password` fields. Keep what the request gives you too ! (token, etc...)

See ya !

Comment: Thx for your swift support. I have changed the url but this doesn't help unfortunately. From your answer I do take away that my general approach is not wrong but that there must be something else I am missing.